# sf::st_combine makes MULTIPOLYGONs with holes

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf, multipolygons

I have some polygons in a `data.frame` called `walktime`.

```
> class(walktime)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

I want to combine the polygons to one. As I understand this is possible with

```
walktime2 <- sf::st_combine(walktime)
> class(walktime2)
[1] "sfc_MULTIPOLYGON" "sfc"
```

But if I plot `walktime2` I have holes in my combined polygon.

[image: LeafletMap of the layer walktime2 has holes]

How can I avoid this?

Thanks for any help.

Reproducable code is here:
https://github.com/StatistikVolker/exp_st_combine_holes

Answer (score 3):

You need `st_union` rather than `st_combine`.

From the docs for `?st_combine`

> st_combine combines geometries without resolving borders, using c.sfg (analogous to c for ordinary vectors).

Whereas

> If st_union is called with a single argument, x, (with y missing) and by_feature is FALSE all geometries are unioned together

So we can resolve your issue by doing:

```r
walktime2 <- st_union(walktime)

KITAmap3 <- KITAmap %>%
  addPolygons(data = walktime2,
              color = "#00A600",
              weight = 0,
              #opacity = 1.0,
              fillOpacity = 1.0
  )
KITAmap3
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
Thanks a lot.